# How to get one JavaScript function to get the value of the html button that called it for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a calculator using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I would like each number button to return the value of the HTML button clicked as an alert for now, to do this I am trying to use a singular JavaScript function to only return the value of the button which called it.

**HTML Code:**

```
    <button id="btn" type="button" class="square left" value="1" onclick="display_num()"><b>1</b></button>
    <button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="2" onclick="display_num()"><b>2</b></button>
    <button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="3" onclick="display_num()"><b>3</b></button>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function display_num() {
var num = document.getElementById("btn").value
alert(num)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise in advance if the HTML is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a reference

```js
function display_num(btn) {
  var num = btn.value
  console.log(num)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square left" value="1" onclick="display_num(this)"><b>1</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="2" onclick="display_num(this)"><b>2</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="3" onclick="display_num(this)"><b>3</b></button>
```

Better answer is to use event delegation

```js
function display_num(evt) {
  const btn = evt.target.closest("button");
  if (!btn) return
  var num = btn.value
  console.log(num)
}

document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", display_num);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="btn" type="button" class="square left" value="1"><b>1</b></button>
  <button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="2"><b>2</b></button>
  <button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="3"><b>3</b></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
html code :

```
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square left" value="1" onclick="display_num(1)"><b>1</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="2" onclick="display_num(2)"><b>2</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="3" onclick="display_num(3)"><b>3</b></button>
```

JavaScript code :

```
 function display_num(num) {
        alert(num)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers) should be passed an event parameter from which you can grab the information you need.

```js
function display_num(e) {
  var num = e.currentTarget.value
  alert(num)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square left" value="1" onclick="display_num(event)"><b>1</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="2" onclick="display_num(event)"><b>2</b></button>
<button id="btn" type="button" class="square" value="3" onclick="display_num(event)"><b>3</b></button>
```